# Supremum of a family of functions

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\mathcal{F} \subset C[0,1]$ consider 
$$g(x)= \sup{ \{f(x)\mid f\in \mathcal{F}} \}$$
Can we say $\exists \{f_n\} \subset \mathcal{F} $ s.t. $f_n \rightarrow g$ pointwise?

Sorry if this is a very easy question, I am a bit confused. From the definition we know that for each $x$ there exists a sequence (depending on $x$) $\{f_n^x\}$ s.t. $f_n^x(x)\rightarrow g(x)$. How can we get a sequence which would be "uniform" and would converge for all $x$? Thank you.

Comment: Beware that if you take $\mathcal{F}=\{f\in C([0,1])\,;\,f\equiv n,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ then $g$ is not well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's false : consider $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x$ and $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x)=1-x$. Then $g=f$ if $x\geq 1/2$ and $g=h$ if $x\leq 1/2$, and there is no sequence in $\mathcal{F}=\{f,h\}$ which verify what you are looking for.

Comment: You should take $h(x)=1-x$. Anyhow, I like your example!

Comment: @BrianO : Thank you, I forgot to put the 1.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net : Yeah I corrected that, thank you !

Comment: For better or worse, I deleted my comment once you fixed it, as now *it* wouldn't make any sense (/would be false). Nice example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  As a counterexample, let $\mathcal F$ be the collection of functions defined over integers $1 \leq k \leq n$ by
$$
f_{{n,k}} = 
\begin{cases}
1 & x \in [(k-1)/n, k/n]\\
[\text{interpolating line}] & x \in [(k-2)/n,(k-1)/n] \cup [k/n,(k+1)/n]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$