# If two lower semicontinuous functions agree on a dense subset of $[0,1]$, are they equal?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f,g : \mathbb [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ are lower-semicontinuous, and $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$ in a dense subset of $[0,1]$, is it true that $f(x) = g(x)$ everywhere in $[0,1]$? If it helps, we can also assume that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ everywhere.

---

The context is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1509864/169852), where $M$ is the pointwise supremum of a family $\mathcal F$ of continuous functions. I have constructed an increasing sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $\mathcal F$ such that $f_n \to L$, and $L(q) = M(q)$ for each $q \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$. So, $L$ and $M$ are LSC and agree on a dense subset, and $L \leq M$ pointwise, but I don't know if this implies agreement everywhere.

I've attempted to find a proof but haven't been able to make it work and I'm not sure whether it's actually true. I would appreciate either a hint or, if it's false, a counterexample and perhaps an additional hypothesis (less restrictive than continuity) that would make it true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. For example,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x\neq 1/2, \\ -1 & \text{if } x = 1/2.\end{cases}$$

and 
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x\neq 1/2, \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 1/2.\end{cases}$$

are the same for $x\neq 1/2$, $f(x) \le g(x)$ but are not the same function.

Comment: Nice and simple :-) I'll have to adjust my proof strategy for the other problem.